# Neo4j Batch CSV Load

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to load data from csvs into Neo4j using the following:

```
WITH ['system1',
'system2',
'system3'] AS systems

UNWIND systems AS system_name

// Get database
//WITH $nodefile AS uri
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///' + system_name + '.csv' AS row
MERGE (n:Database {name:row.schema})
SET n.name = row.schema
;
```

I'm getting this error.  What am I missing?
[Neo4j Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyMF7.png)

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using my own test data.

Can you try below script?

```
WITH ['system1',
'system2',
'system3'] AS systems

UNWIND systems AS system_name
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///' + system_name + '.csv' AS row
WITH row WHERE row.schema IS NOT NULL
MERGE (n:Database {name: row.schema});
```

You don't need the last line: SET n.name = row.schema because using merge will create new nodes if that name doesn't exists.

Comment: thanks I figured out the issue.  I currently have this 
`WITH ['system1',
'system2',
'system3'] AS systems

UNWIND systems AS system_name
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///' + system_name + '.csv' AS row
MERGE (n:Database {name:row.schema});
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///' + system_name + '.csv' AS row
MATCH (db:Database {name:row.schema})
MATCH (table:Table {name:row.table_name})
MERGE (db) -[:HAS]-> (table);`
The second load is throwing the error. Is there a way to have 1 UNWIND for multiple loads?

Comment: you can have unwind with 2 subqueries `UNWIND ... AS system_name CALL { WITH system_name LOAD RETURn count(*) } CALL { ... }`